# How to enable users to insert an infinity number

Tags: website-design, input-fields, input, web, css

I am designing a web page which give admin users the opportunity to manage the users below them. in one section of this admin page, the admin user is required to fill out how many queries he permits to each user below him to run in this system (i.e. queries limit).

This input looks like this:

[image]

The admin can enter a number in this box, increase it or decrease it.

The problem is: the admin should have an option to permit the user to run an `infinity` queries, i.e. not limit the number of queries he can run.

It should look something like this:

[image]

How can I manage allow the users to enter an infinity number, in an efficient and clean way?

Comment: Maybe I'm quibbling (don't know if it's my math background, or English?), but your users can't enter an infinite number of queries.  They have the option of entering an unlimited number.  And as others point out in answers, if you frame the question that way, the solution becomes obvious: a "limit/unlimit" checkbox, and a number entry field that appears when "limit" is selected.

Comment: How high can the number of queries go? e.g. 10, 100, 1000? Having a `+` / `-` suggests that making adjustments by one makes sense, which would suggest that only very low numbers for the limit of queries makes sense

Comment: That's simple: users should be able to enter infinity by pressing + infinite number of times.

Comment: @el.pescado: Won't work.  On a 32-bit machine, you only get to 4294967295 queries (assuming unsigned int type) before it wraps.  64 bits gets you a bit more, but still will wrap around eventually.  Maybe the OP could wait until Intel releases their forthcoming "Hilbert Hotel" infinite word length processor :-)

Comment: You should use the word "unlimited" rather than "infinity" on the screen, by the way.

Comment: @jamesqf Yeah, and while you wait, you can kill time by pressing the `+` button until the 64 bit counter wraps around.

Comment: Use 0 for infinite

Comment: @Paparazzi 0 is presumably a reasonable limit. "How many queries are users allowed to execute?" "None." It might be less than useful, depending on the rest of the system's functionality... but it appears to be a viable number.

Comment: -1, on the other hand, @Delioth is not a reasonable limit value and would be a good stand-in for infinity ("-1 to disable" is pretty common).

Comment: @jamesqf Tags include "website-design", so you're looking at [9007199254740991](https://stackoverflow.com/a/307200/500202)

Comment: Don't use the word *infinity* or any symbol for *infinity*, which are mathematical terms with very special meaning. Consider instead using normal English words. "No limit" is most certainly what you really mean in this case.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

**Add a checkbox labelled *'Limit number of queries'***.

And only make the input field active if this checkbox is checked.

---

*Alternatively* if you must use the infinity icon, **keep it simple** and place it to the right of the '+' button, in the same style.

[image: Infinity button]

This would also adhere to the perception of hierarchy.

*i.e*. the left button decreases the value, and the right button increases the value, so a button even further right should increase the value even more.

It's also worth **disabling the infinity button** if the value is already infinity, to make the user aware of the allowable (or *dis*allowable) operations.

Comment: Both are good answers, but I would use the alternate suggestion. Check the check box by default if that is what most users will be doing. Then uncheck it automatically when a number is entered, or if + is pressed, and then if - is clicked when the number is 1, then auto check it again.

Comment: What happens if I press the `-` button when the current state is "infinity"? How many is "infinity minus one" ? The advantage of a "limit number of queries" checkbox is that it enables/disables the limit setting, but a disabled setting can still be shown greyed out and remember a previous value.

Comment: You would have the minus button disabled in this case. But agreed my second suggestion is more suitable in this situation.

Comment: I think "disabling" is the wrong word and/or behavior here. Maybe the button should be displayed as "active" instead. Then if you want to disable the infinity, you click it again to make the button inactive. If it is disabled, how can you go back to hard limits?

Comment: Seems like "allow unlimited queries?" would be a more intuitive phrasing

Comment: I chose the phrasing because it implies mutual exclusivity with the input field, and makes it clear that the checkbox enables/disables that input.

Comment: I don't have a source for this, but I think the commonly accepted approach would be for either of `-` or `+` to merely restore what value was present before clicking infinity.

Comment: Indeed, or at the *very* least return to the default value.

Comment: You aren't allowing an *infinite* number users; you are allowing an *arbitrary* number of users. Don't mix the two concepts.

Comment: In my experience, from a UX perspective users have a better understanding  of the term 'infinite' than they do 'arbitrary'.

Comment: @chepner True, in reality, the number of queries a user actually conducts will always be an arbitrary, finite number, but the *limit* for the number of queries (which the input defines) *is* infinite.

Comment: @JoelTebbett That's because ordinary users probably don't understand the distinction either. Better to avoid reinforcing their incorrect notion of infinity.

Comment: As @maxathousand says, it's not an incorrect notion of infinity. Besides, how exactly is providing them with a term they don't understand meant to improve their user experience? For this purpose, *infinity* acts in the way a user would expect. Pedantry isn't an excuse for bad UX.

Comment: @chepner This design is to allow an *arbitrary number of queries* within an *infinite limit*. The UI control is to define the limit, for which infinity is a perfectly appropriate possible value.

Comment: @maxathousand there always is a limit, and is a finite one because of hardware resources etc.

Comment: @el.pescado Okay, but that's not the user's concern. For example, Google let's you sync "unlimited" photos to their servers... they don't bother the user with telling them how much available storage space they have allotted for user photos... This feels like argument for the sake of argument.

Comment: @maxathousand note "unlimited" (i.e without additional artificial limit imposed), not "infinite"

Comment: @el.pescado [Unlimited](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unlimited), definition 2 from Merriam-Webster is "`boundless, infinite`". Agree to disagree, I suppose.

Comment: @maxathousand Ok, I get your point

Answer (score 108):

How about using something like this?

[image]

Comment: I agree with this; don't do an "infinity" button.  Also, you should hide number input unless they check the box.  Without the box being checked; the number input is irrelevant.

Comment: This is also much easier to implement in the backend.  How does the infinity respond when you click +/-?  Do you then have to put in a special condition to read the infinity symbol?  How are you passing the "infinite" value to the back end?  -1?  Just do the check box.

Comment: I think it could also be useful for an infinity symbol to appear in the number input box if "limit number of queries" is selected and the +/- buttons could become greyed out. Personally, I would like this numeric cue to instantly give me feedback about what checking this box actually does, or at least confirm that it does what I expect.

Comment: @syntonicC you mean the opposite, right?

Comment: @Hansteriffic Ahh, sorry I totally misread the question. I'll delete my comment later.

Comment: The number field and the +/- buttons should be greyed out unless "Limit number of queries" is checked.

Answer (score 12):

This seems very close to a very common pattern for pagination by limiting searches per page, e.g. [datatables](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/length_menu.html):

[image]

In your case you only want to display the first page, but it's still pretty much the same concept.

1. Then instead of 'infinity' seeing as you're talking about limits, **'unlimited'** or **'none'** would do.
2. This gets rid of all the complexity around [@MSalter's question "what's infinity - 1?"](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/110612/how-to-enable-users-to-insert-an-infinity-number#comment178922_110613).
3. You keep it as one input

**Edit:** As other's have commented, this would work well as radio buttons:

[image]

**Edit:** From [@FKEinternet's comment](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/110612/how-to-enable-users-to-insert-an-infinity-number/110654?noredirect=1#comment179113_110654) there is indeed an example of this in the Windows power options:

[image]

and further to that, in the advanced options, they use '0' as an infinity placeholder which gets replaced with 'Never':

[image]

**Edit:** I'm assuming here that users will have a relatively small set of options for the query limits. If every single user can potentially have a different limit, then a number input makes more sense. However if there is a common set of limits, then you have the benefit here that you combine the two inputs into one.

Comment: Man, how I hate combo boxes foir numeric entry...

Comment: click the combobox and type the number

Comment: Yes, assuming these are manually entered queries (not run by a script), all you probably need are options like 5, 20, 100, and unlimited. I doubt it needs to be more finely adjustable. Maybe even go with radio buttons. This makes for one or two click entry for any value including “infinity,” which is probably more efficient than the OP's design. It also cues the user on what are reasonable values to enter, saving the user some thinking time.

Comment: @MichaelZuschlag yes - radio buttons was a definite possibility

Comment: Good answer, there really seems to be no go reason to allow users to have 37 or 413 queries. A limited number of round figures and one "unlimited" option should be good enough for everyone. Giving users more options that they would ever need only adds friction, and is a nuisance best avoided.

Comment: @MaskedMan Just because *you* can't see a reason why an arbitrary number shouldn't be allowed doesn't mean there isn't a good reason.  *I* frequently find that "a limited number of round figures" prevents me from making the selection I want (most recent example, "leave drives on" settings in winDoze power manager) which *adds friction* and is "a nuisance best avoided" - if there isn't a *specific, legitimate reason* for limiting users' options to a small range of values, you should *not* restrict their options.

Comment: @el.pescado perhaps I should clarify this. Using the dropdown only realy works if you've just got a few options. If there is really a fine grained requirement to enter a value between 1-100 then yes you want a simple number. But my guess is that for specifying query limits only a few options are required. As other's here suggest, it would be better if they were radio buttons so only one click is required.

Comment: @FKEinternet it would entirely depend on the OP's requirements. If every single user could potentially have a different amount of queries allowed, then a free form input makes sense. But if there is a common set of levels then it makes sense to have a dropdown. You then have the benefit that you can include 'unlimited' as part of the same control.

Comment: @FKEinternet How frequently do you use the application that the OP is designing here? I did not say, "always give a small list of choices" or "choosing arbitrary values is never necessary". I have no idea what your Losedoze setting of "leave drives on" has anything to do with the admin page that the OP is talking about.

Comment: @FKEinternet I would be interested to know a usecase where a user *must* choose 47 as the upper limit for number of queries *where 50 won't do*.

Comment: @FKEinternet, thanks for pointing me at the Windows Power Options (like it or hate it, it's probably the most well known usage of this kind of pattern). Where as the dropdown is only limited they do have advanced options where you can set it via a number input - I've added it to my answer

Answer (score 10):

In scenarios where a setting of zero does not make sense, zero is sometimes used for infinity. It does not really make sense but I think I've seen it in more than one application so as a user I'd see it as reasonable behavior. Of course it's important to add a label like "0 for no limit". The upside to this approach is that it uses a standard UI component and needs no conditional logic for hiding the control.

Comment: Or "0" could mean => no queries for you.

Comment: @Fernando That obviously wouldn't be a setting where zero doesn't make sense. I've seen this in many applications.

Comment: Using 0 to represent something other than 0 is an implementation detail that shouldn't be exposed to the user in a good interface.

Comment: In data storage situations, it's common to use negative numbers to represent a special case.  In this case 0 could have a meaning "searching is disabled for this user" but you could use -1 to represent "unlimited" and present that as one of the above UI options.

Comment: Having 0 or -1 as a 'special' value might be common, imho its a hack and  shouldn't be encouraged. It's not intuitive & requires explanation to the user. Needs different handling for values without option (0 or negatives are valid choices) resulting in mixed paradigms. Code uses signed datatypes when an unsigned one would be best. Those numbers are special because the code uses them specially. Also a hack best avoided since it can lead to bugs when code forgets to consider the 'special' state. Just have a proper flag variable.

Comment: 0 = no-limit is common in config files, but less common in end-user UIs, I think.  If only admins can set limit=0, then this design choice may still make sense.

Comment: To prevent confusion, rather than letting 0 denote no-limit, consider replacing the 0 with the infinity sign, or simply the text 'No limit'

Comment: As @PeterCordes says, using `0` to _store_ the fact that there is no limit is fine, but not how a modern UI would _render_ that fact.

Comment: "using 0 to store the fact that there is no limit is fine"  Heck no.  Magic values are bad.  Just because they are sometimes used as a hack doesn't mean we should encourage or *design* for their use.

Answer (score 10):

Given the OP's wording of his question, I would implement Joel Tebbett's first suggestion this way:

[image: unlimited checkbox]

This would adhere to the perception of heirarchy as noted in his second option.

Answer (score 2):

While possibly not the best suggestion i have seen many interfaces that address this constraint by allowing a -1 input with a meaning of (unlimited)

See references to software using this "https://www.google.com/search?q=%22enter+-1+for+unlimited%22"

Answer (score 1):

Just accept empty inputs.

A limit of infity is the same as no limit.
If the input is properly labeled, leaving a field labeled as "limit" blank really says, that there should be no limit.

Depending on the background of the users and the importance of people knowing that infinity is an option, this can be made obvious to all people by placing a small hint like "leave blank for no limit" next to the input.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to remember that not everybody understands what "infinity" is, or what the infinity symbol means. This is another reason to go with some variation of limit (unlimited, no limit, etc.) rather than using an infinity symbol.

**I recommend designing an interface that sets a reasonable default based on the most common use case for administrators.**

If the most common use case is that users **have no query limits, but when they do it is specific**:

[image]

If the most common use case is that users **have no query limits, but when they do it is unspecific**:

[image]

If the most common use case is that users have **query limits, but the number needs to be specific**:

[image]

If the most common use case is that users have **query limits, but the exact number is not important**:

[image]